# Retrieving complex api information and putting it in a listviewbuilder

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, api

I am trying to create an mobile app where i can put in a name and get information from an api afterwards, this was working until the api got more complex. can share this information btw. It is showing nothing but the image.
api that works when i retrieve it:

```
{"id":"Pw_wOwAmqDmB3slQO_8PkKXLoE56qnBk5f-qdW0fKVTfvAmm",
"accountId":"_MkPpRhr6tK22xRT8TofYHPyACcmURn0cp-U9GbL1xTQzhRfvaw4ZF7P",
"puuid":"RT0wLpw9fOUMgB4HUWDVoMi6_F20W4yhut5-q1bA7Izhl3dPjv5iF2JzqXkLQJYPtf2MBMcvooMmGA",
"name":"Zeri outplay",
"profileIconId":5610,"revisionDate":1669140463310,
"summonerLevel":535}
```

api that doesnt work:

```
[{"leagueId":"e6a38c93-6037-4457-aa57-80a9a52be3ea",
"queueType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
"tier":"PLATINUM","rank":"IV",
"summonerId":"Pw_wOwAmqDmB3slQO_8PkKXLoE56qnBk5f-qdW0fKVTfvAmm",
"summonerName":"Zeri outplay",
"leaguePoints":0,
"wins":75,
"losses":56,
"veteran":false,
"inactive":false,
"freshBlood":false,
"hotStreak":false},
{"leagueId":"a21014e6-fa8f-4f07-b533-b09a10b88bbf",
"queueType":"RANKED_FLEX_SR",
"tier":"SILVER","rank":"II",
"summonerId":"Pw_wOwAmqDmB3slQO_8PkKXLoE56qnBk5f-qdW0fKVTfvAmm",
"summonerName":"Zeri outplay",
"leaguePoints":1,
"wins":15,
"losses":5,
"veteran":false,
"inactive":false,
"freshBlood":false,
"hotStreak":true}]
```

heres the code for the api that doesnt work:
RemoteService.dart:

```
class SummonerRankApi {
  static Future getSummonerRank(summonerid) {
    String link = 'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/$summonerid?api_key=$apiKey';
    return http.get(Uri.parse(link));
  }
}
```

Home_page.dart

```
class SummonerProfileRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  String name, summonerId;
  int profileIconId;
  SummonerProfileRoute(this.name, this.summonerId, this.profileIconId);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SummonerProfileRouteState(this.name, this.summonerId, this.profileIconId);
  }}

class _SummonerProfileRouteState extends State<SummonerProfileRoute> {
  List<SummonerRank> SummonerRankList = <SummonerRank>[];

  void getSummonerRankfromApi() async {
    SummonerRankApi.getSummonerRank(summonerId).then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        SummonerRankList = list.map((model) => SummonerRank.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }

  String name, summonerId;
  int profileIconId;
  _SummonerProfileRouteState(this.name, this.summonerId, this.profileIconId);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSummonerRankfromApi();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image(
                image: NetworkImage('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/img/profileicon/$profileIconId.png'),
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: SummonerRankList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(SummonerRankList[index].tier),
                      subtitle: Text(SummonerRankList[index].summonerName),
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

summoner.dart

```
class SummonerRank {
  String leagueId;
  String queueType;
  String tier;
  String rank;
  String summonerId;
  String summonerName;
  int leaguePoints;
  int wins;
  int losses;
  bool veteran;
  bool inactive;
  bool freshBlood;
  bool hotStreak;

  SummonerRank.fromJson(Map json)
      : leagueId = json['leagueId'],
        queueType = json['queueType'],
        tier = json['tier'],
        rank = json['rank'],
        summonerId = json['summonerId'],
        summonerName = json['summonerName'],
        leaguePoints = json['leaguePoints'],
        wins = json['wins'],
        losses = json['losses'],
        veteran = json['veteran'],
        inactive = json['inactive'],
        freshBlood = json['freshBlood'],
        hotStreak = json['hotStreak'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {'leagueId': leagueId, 'queueType': queueType, 'tier': tier, 'rank': rank,
      'summonerId': summonerId, 'summonerName': summonerName, 'leaguePoints': leaguePoints, 'wins': wins,
      'losses': losses, 'veteran': veteran, 'inactive': inactive, 'freshBlood': freshBlood, 'hotStreak': hotStreak};
  }
}
```

I tried building it with a futurebuilder and also with a gridviewbuilder both of them did not work. however i do think i know why it isnt working but im not really capable of explaining it well. it probably has something to do with that the api that isnt working is an array (i think)

Comment: What do you mean by not working?
Is it throwing any exception? or Is it not rendering the data in widgets?

Comment: @Vettiyanakan it just shows nothing now, the only thing working is the image.

Comment: Try log the current index data before this line `return ListTile(`.

Comment: This might be a size related issue (widget size).

Comment: logging the same data  before the ```return ListTile``` also returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `ListView.builder()` in an `Expanded()` widget.

Posting a working sample. **(Same code different API)**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class SummonerProfileRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  String name, summonerId;
  int profileIconId;
  SummonerProfileRoute(this.name, this.summonerId, this.profileIconId);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _SummonerProfileRouteState(
        this.name, this.summonerId, this.profileIconId);
  }
}

class _SummonerProfileRouteState extends State<SummonerProfileRoute> {
  List<SummonerRank> SummonerRankList = <SummonerRank>[];

  void getSummonerRankfromApi() async {
    SummonerRankApi.getSummonerRank().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        SummonerRankList =
            list.map((model) => SummonerRank.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }

  String name, summonerId;
  int profileIconId;
  _SummonerProfileRouteState(this.name, this.summonerId, this.profileIconId);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSummonerRankfromApi();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Image(
            image: NetworkImage(
                'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/img/profileicon/$profileIconId.png'),
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: SummonerRankList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(SummonerRankList[index].title!),
                    subtitle: Text(SummonerRankList[index].body!),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

class SummonerRank {
  int? userId;
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? body;
  SummonerRank({
    this.userId,
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.body,
  });

  SummonerRank.fromJson(Map json)
      : userId = json['userId'],
        id = json['id'],
        title = json['title'],
        body = json['body'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {
      'userId': userId,
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'body': body,
    };
  }
}

class SummonerRankApi {
  static Future getSummonerRank() {
    String link = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    return http.get(Uri.parse(link));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! it worked ty alot, can you give me some insights to why this does work now? would appreciate it. still thanks alot

Comment: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

Comment: Here the ListView have given unlimited space. By wrapping it in Expanded it will have only the space available in visible area.